Smooth approximation of rectified linear function
I came across this post on how to approximate the absolute function $|x|$ using a smooth function.
I was wondering if it's possible to approximate the rectified linear function (ReLU) using a smooth function.
More specifically, I'm looking for an approximation of $f(x, a, b, L) = L + \max\left(b\left(x-a\right),\ 0\right)$, where $a, b, L > 0$, the gradient of which is not continuous at $x=a$. I'm looking for an approximation that works well within gradient based optimization algorithms, like Hamiltonian Monte Carlo.
I am also interested in the parameter values of $a, b$ after fitting this function through some data.
Thanks for any help!

Your function $f(x,a,b,L) = L + \max(b(x-a),0)$ can be obtained from the basic "ramp" function $R(x) = \max(x,0)$ via shifting and rescaling:
\begin{equation}
f(x,a,b,L) = L + R(b(x-a))
\end{equation}
Therefore it suffices to find a smooth approximation to $R(x)$, from which $f(x,a,b,L)$ can be obtained for any values of $a$, $b$, and $L$. $R(x)$ can be written as the integral of the Heaviside step function
\begin{equation}
H(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & x > 0\\
0 & x < 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
(For the purposes of this answer, the value of $H(0)$ doesn't matter.) That is:
\begin{equation}
R(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x H(y)\, dy \qquad\qquad (1)
\end{equation}
Now, a useful approximation to $H(x)$ is
\begin{equation}
H(x) \approx \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \tanh\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)\right)\, ,\qquad\qquad (2)
\end{equation}
where $\epsilon$ is some small positive number. Plugging this approximation into Eq. (1) yields:
\begin{equation}
R(x) \approx \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \tanh\left(\frac{y}{\epsilon}\right)\right)\, dy
\;=\; 
\frac{1}{2}\left(x + \epsilon\log\left(2\cosh\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)\right)\right)\qquad (3)
\end{equation}
For gradient-based algorithms, this approximation of $R(x)$ has the advantage that its derivative is given simply by Eq. (2). Eq. (3) is plotted below for $\epsilon = 0.05$.


$R(x)$ itself can be expressed as $\frac12(x+|x|)$, so any of the smooth approximations of $|x|$ in the Q&A linked by the OP yields such an approximation of $R(x)$ (and thus of $f(x,a,b,L)$ as well).

@Semiclassical Good point.

@Semiclassical is there a way to adjust $\epsilon$ with $b$ that can upper bound the absolute error between the smooth approximation and the original function at $x=a$? What I notice with any approximation is that this error is large for very small values of $b$

@chesslad It depends on how you quantify the error. The max deviation between the exact $f(x,a,b,L)$ and the smoothed approximation provided by John Barber is $\epsilon\cdot \frac12\ln 2$. The error interval, by contrast, is of order $\epsilon/b$ in width. Finally, the integrated error (the area between the two curves) is $\pi^2 \epsilon^2/(24b)$. So if $b$ is small then we need $\epsilon^2$ to be even smaller to keep the integrated error down.

@Semiclassical That is very helpful. Thanks!

For the ramp function you could use as approximation for a real-valued $a>0$:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \dfrac{x}{1-e^{-ax}},\quad x\neq 0\\ \dfrac{1}{a},\quad x=0
\end{cases}$$
which could be made as closed as desire by increasing the value of $a$. You could see its plot on this question:

